# Get pageX and pageY from Google Maps Mouseover

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Adding a listener to `mousemove` and inspecting the event with `console.log` yields an object:

`{qE {latLng: Q, Sa: MouseEvent, pixel: undefined, ca: undefined, ...}}`

I'm looking to extract the `pageX` and `pageY` attributes of the `{Sa: MouseEvent}` object.

I know I can access them with `event.Sa.pageX` and `event.Sa.pageY`. But, as far as I know, the `Sa` object isn't documented anywhere. Is there another, more robust way to access `pageX` and `pageY`? I'm just worried about it breaking in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pageX and pageY are properties of the DOM-event, it appears the event you observe is a [`google.maps.MouseEvent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MouseEvent), which does not expose the requested properties.

Use `addDomListener` instead to observe the DOM-event(of the node that contains the map):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(map.getDiv(), 'mouseover', function(e){
   console.log(e.pageX+','+e.pageY);
});
```

Comment: what if the event is not being bound to the `map.getDiv()`, but rather, a polygon? Then, the `e` object still does not contain `pageX` and `pageY` unless I proxy through the `Sa` object.

Comment: You should not access the property `Sa`, this label may change with the next API-version(I just checked it, for 3.10 it was `Ja` and for 3.11 it was `Ra`). What you can do: iterate over all properties of the PolyMouseEvent,  the property that contains the DOM-MouseEvent will have the constructor `MouseEvent` . However, as this property isn't documented you can't rely on the fact that the PolyMouseEvent will  expose a property that contains the DOM-MouseEvent.

Comment: Now iterating over properties of the event and finding the property that has a constructor with MouseEvent name. Dirty, but it works :) -- Thank you.

Comment: A lesson learned... the constructor's name is different depending on the browser. You must check for Chrome, FF, and Safari differently: `if(e != undefined && (e.constructor.name == 'MouseEvent')||(e.constructor.toString() == '[object MouseEvent]')||(e.constructor.toString() == '[object MouseEventConstructor]')){}`